# Need guidance on making web service that copy and modify website like Google Translate Website

Tags: amazon-web-services, translation, google-translate

I am comfortable to use AWS. I learned that Google Translate Website can modify texts of other website without subject to cross-site scripting because those website came from their own server. (probably copied)

I need some guidance in doing this. From original URL, you get the same page from your own (temp) URL. Thank you.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: What is not clear? I want a web service that take a URL as an input, then serve me an HTML that is the same as the original URL but came from my own server. That way I can modify it like how Google Translate Website did.